# I can't install CoreOS to disk

Tags: installation, coreos

I'm trying to install CoreOS to disk, and I'm following the recomendation from [official doc](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/installing-to-disk/).
I have PXE with CoreOS, then I'm booting CoreOS from RAM and I continue these steps:

1. execute: `cfdisk -z /dev/sda`
2. execute: `touch "/usr.squashfs (deleted)" # work around a bug in mkfs.btrfs 3.12`
3. execute: `mkfs.btrfs -L ROOT /dev/sda1`
4. copy all resources to /home/core (coreos-install and my-cloud-config.yml)
5. execute: `chmod +x coreos install`
6. execute: `sudo ./coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c /home/core/my-cloud-config.yml`

The output was:

```
...

Installing cloud-config...
[2312.930275] BTRFS info (device sda1): disk space caching is enabled
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what's the problem, because on internet I can't find any report of this behavior during the installation of CoreOS.